# reformatting table in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, reformatting

I'm working on pulling information from a table on a website. The output of the table looks like this (see below).

```
1. Saturday
2. 4:00 PM
3. 5:30 PM
4. Sunday
5. 8:30 AM
6. 10:00 AM
```

I really need it to come through like this (see below). I don't think I can transform it with the `html_table()` function, but I was hoping someone knows how to reformat it after the fact in R.

```
1. Saturday    4:00 PM
2. Saturday    5:30 PM
3. Sunday      8:30 AM
4. Sunday      10:00 AM
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
urls <- 'https://www.life.church/edmond/'

times <- function(x){ 
  try( x %>%
         read_html()%>%
         html_table(header = F)%>%
         data.frame(x))

}


#Apply function to the urls
m <- lapply(urls, times)

#Convert to a dataframe 
data <-data.frame(unnest(tibble(m)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I would do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

times <- function(x){ 
  try(
    x %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_table(header = FALSE) %>% 
      flatten() %>% 
      as_tibble()
  )
}

urls <- c('https://www.life.church/edmond/', 'https://www.life.church/fortworth/')

lapply(urls, times) %>% 
  set_names(urls) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "URL") %>% 
  separate(X1, into = c("Time", "Day"), sep = "(?=^\\D)") %>% 
  fill(Day) %>% 
  filter(Time != "") %>% 
  select(URL, Day, Time)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 16 x 3
>    URL                                Day       Time    
>    <chr>                              <chr>     <chr>   
>  1 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Saturday  4:00 PM 
>  2 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Saturday  5:30 PM 
>  3 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Sunday    8:30 AM 
>  4 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Sunday    10:00 AM
>  5 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Sunday    11:30 AM
>  6 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Sunday    1:00 PM 
>  7 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Sunday    4:00 PM 
>  8 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Sunday    5:30 PM 
>  9 https://www.life.church/edmond/    Wednesday 7:00 PM 
> 10 https://www.life.church/fortworth/ Saturday  4:00 PM 
> 11 https://www.life.church/fortworth/ Saturday  5:30 PM 
> 12 https://www.life.church/fortworth/ Sunday    8:30 AM 
> 13 https://www.life.church/fortworth/ Sunday    10:00 AM
> 14 https://www.life.church/fortworth/ Sunday    11:30 AM
> 15 https://www.life.church/fortworth/ Sunday    1:00 PM 
> 16 https://www.life.church/fortworth/ Wednesday 7:00 PM
> ```

`separate()` uses a look-ahead regular expression to separate the entries which are *not* starting with a digit into new column `Day`

Comment: You're brilliant! Thank you!